# How create a module with asynchronous exports in NodeJS with ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to create a module (install in node_modules) for my projects which call the same API. But when I export my async function I get an error :

```
index.js Unexpected token (3:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Index.js is my module file.

Here's example code:

```
export default async function({path, method = 'GET', body}, userToken = null, contentType = 'application/json') {
     // some code here ...
}
```

And in my project I import like this :

```
import invokeApi from 'my_sdk';
```

Comment: Try `const myFun = async function...` then `export const myFun` then import as `import {myFun} from 'my_sdk'`

Comment: This looks like a webpack error, are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes it's probably a configuration problem. I use this module in a react application with react-scripts (version 0.9.5). So webpack is in react package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue with your build configuration on the consumer code side. You must enable async/await when consuming async APIs as it requires regeneration runtime (or install [Node 7.6 or later](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) as it brings native async/await support).

If you use this code on the web you might probably need to [`import 'babel-polyfill'`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) in the entry point file (probably main.js, app.js or index.js) and set up [Webpack to use Babel to transpile your code](https://gist.github.com/thejmazz/067295d9fb8b22c77be0).

Works like a charm using [babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) with following `"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]`:

*asyncModule.js*

```
const sleep = async duration => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration))

export default async function({path, method = 'GET', body}, userToken = null, contentType = 'application/json') {
 await sleep(500)
 return "Hello :)"
}
```

*index.js*

```
import asyncExample from './asyncModule'

const main = async () => {
  const result = await asyncExample({path: '/', body: ''});
  console.log(result)

main();
```

*npm start*

`"start": "babel-node --presets es2015 index.js"`

Comment: Yes it's probably a configuration problem. I use this module in a react application with react-scripts (version 0.9.5). How I can use babel-node or polyfill with react-scripts ?

Comment: Please update your [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) to 1.0.0 along with [`create-react-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) as it should support async/await by default now [according to Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/768810510401798144).

Comment: It seems to be ok ! Thanks a lot !!